# How to detect GTV back to home window or launch a new activity

Tags: google-tv

Google TV have a home button which let user come back to home window.

How to figure out it's not a new app launched? I think normally when we back to home, we can keep our app active (activity paused at this moment), e.g. keep video playing.
But if it launch a new app, we should stop video and release resources.

Answer (score 0):

When your app looses [AudioFocus](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) you should pause/stop your video.  Alternatively, you can just use the normal [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), and override onPause() and then stop / pause then. You would then resume when onResume() was called.

Comment: AudioFocus could be monitored to handle it, but not all application will request audio focus when it just launch,